# How to use React Hook Form with RNPickerSelect in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hook-form

I am trying to use RNPickerSelect (https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select) with react-hook-form in React Native. I've tried with Controller wrapper to use RNPickerSelect component. And it always invokes 'required' error. Could someone please point me to right direction? Here is my code.

```
const CategoryContentView = () => {
   const tempData = [];
   categories.forEach((data) => {
     tempData.push({ label: `${data.name}`, value: `${data.id}` });
   });
   return (
     <>
       <Controller
         as={
           <RNPickerSelect
           onValueChange={(value) => {
             setCategory(value);
           }}
           items={tempData}
         />}
         rules={{
         required: true,
       }}
         control={control}
         name="category"
         valueName="value"
         onChange={([value]) => value}
         error={!!get(errors, 'category')}
       />
       {errors.category && <ErrorView errors={['this is required']} />}
     </>
 };
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think this should be easier with `render` prop if you are using V6. if you have to use V5, you will have to figure the onChangeName and valueName.

Comment: I am using react-hook-form V5. And tried a lot to figure it out. but failed every time. Could you please write me an example? Where is onChangeName props?

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably late but here is the example:

```
<Controller
render={({onChange, ...props}) => {
    <RNPickerSelect
      {...props}
      onValueChange={(value) => {
        onChange(value);
      }}
      items={tempData}
    />
  }}
  rules={{
    required: true,
  }}
  control={control}
  name="category"
  valueName="value"
  error={!!get(errors, "category")}
/>;
```

So, **render** prop is actually a function that has a couple of parameters and **onChange** is one of them. This method should be called every time you want to update your value and that's why I called it inside a **onValueChange** as you can see it in the example.

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know.